# how do I debug or log laravel trait "AuthenticatesUsers"

Tags: laravel, debugging, traits

I am able to use dd(), var_dump() and Log in controller class but these commands does not work in AuthenticateUsers trait or any other trait. How are we suppose to debug the traits? Is it possible? I am using laravel's builtin authentication module but with doctrine.

Comment: all these commands are working in throttleslogins trait but not in authenticatesusers trait

Answer (score 0):

There is a log file in storage/logs/laravel.log

try there...

Comment: it does not write the logs i create in AuthenticateUsers trait. Logs created from other classes/files can be seen in log file